# "No suitable Driver were found" getting this error

Tags: java, mysql, war

I'm making a simple registration program as i click submit into my IDE log i'm getting this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:8888/login
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at Register.doPost(Register.java:18)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1017)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
13-May-2014 10:09:48.900 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory D:\apache-tomcat-8.0.5\webapps\manager
```

Into my IDE seems `database` is connected successfully.
even i've added Mysql connector to library.

here is my screenshot [click here](http://postimg.org/image/qzmpfp52v/)

plZ help, Help would be appreciated!!

here is my code for `Registration.java`

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Register extends HttpServlet{
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException{

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

        String n=request.getParameter("name");
        String p=request.getParameter("password");
        String e=request.getParameter("email");
        String c=request.getParameter("userCountry");

        try{
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8888/login", "root", "1234"
            );

            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into REGISTERUSER values(?, ?, ?, ?)");

            ps.setString(1,n);
            ps.setString(2,p);
            ps.setString(3,e);
            ps.setString(4,c);

            int i=ps.executeUpdate();
            if(i>0){
                out.print("Registered successfully..");
            }

        }catch(Exception d){d.printStackTrace();}
        out.close();
    }
}
```

and here is my html file `register.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="Register" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name">
    Email: <input type="text" name="email">
    Password: <input type="password" name="password">
    Country:

    <select name="userCountry">
        <option>India</option>
        <option>Pakistan</option>
        <option>Other</option>
    </select><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="register">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java web applications, third party libraries go in WEB-INF/lib folder. Copy the jar inside this folder and redeploy your application. Do this in case your application should support these libraries on every application server (Tomcat, Jetty, JBoss, GlassFish, etc.) it will be deployed.

Comment: You can also add the jdbc driver to the container's lib/ folder (e.g. Tomcat's lib folder) so that you do not need to deploy the jdbc driver with every single app.

Comment: Sorry but i still don't get you... I'm using intellij idea and i already added `Mysql connector into my library ... did you see my screen shot??

Comment: Incorrect - Tomcat 7 and higher require that you put it in the Tomcat /lib folder, not at the project level.

Comment: @user3631223 Tomcat or any other application server will look only into WEB-INF/lib folder for jars. If you place the jars somewhere else, they won't be loaded.

Comment: It depends on what you do, doesn't it? If you manage connections yourself, the driver needs to be available to the application. If you create a datasource in Tomcat, then the driver needs to be available to Tomcat. In this case its the application creating the connections, so deploying with the application (in WEB-INF/lib) should be enough. But perhaps there is some mysterious inner working of Tomcat that I don't know about.

Comment: Not true: Scroll down to DriverManager section in docs.  http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Comment: No man i did the same thing as you said but still it's giving me this error `3-May-2014 10:26:19.212 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:8888/login`

Comment: @user3631223 please post an image or show how your project structure looks now.

Comment: pls see [this](http://postimg.org/image/eshbenrm5/) and [this one](http://postimg.org/image/57ts70rwb/)

Comment: @user3631223 from your images, the library is in WEB-INF folder, not inside lib folder...

Comment: I added into lib folder but still getting the same errors, i guess it's something problem with `MySql Jconnector`..

Comment: Finallly resolved my issue after adding `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

Answer (score 1):

No suitable driver suggests that the class loader found the JAR, but your connection URL is incorrect.

Here are the MySQL docs for Connector/J:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-info.html

The default port for MySQL is 3306.  Are you sure your local host is listening on 8888?

Bad code.  Scriptlets don't belong in JSP.  You don't close any SQL resources in finally blocks.

Comment: This error means that no registered driver understands the URL - which can easily also mean that the driver simply doesn't exist. If the port is wrong, you'd get a connection refused type of error.

Comment: No, My port isn't wrong, as i mentioned with screenshot you can see there, My database is connected.. :p

Comment: +1 for bad code. @user3631223 so you have manually changed MySQL to listen on 8888?

Comment: If you type "netstat -a" in a command shell, is there something LISTENING on port 8888?  Can you connect via the MySQL admin?

Answer (score 0):

1)add driver jar file to your build path
2)add  `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` in your code.

eg:

```
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8888/login", "root", "1234"
        );
```